# Tensorflow Java cannot parse GraphDef from byte array

Tags: java, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am trying to load a TensorFlow model from a byte array or Input Stream. This is how I am doing it similar to the documentation [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d4c048beee1bb8a494c4de4675ee009fd79283a2/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java#L112):

```
 String modelPath = "<model directory>/saved_model.pb"
 byte[] modelAsByte = Files.readAllBytes(modelPath);
 g.importGraphDef(GraphDef.parseFrom(modelAsByte));
```

However the GraphDef.parseFrom throws the exception:

> Method threw 'com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException' exception. While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.

The model was saved using keras SavedModel API and is loaded correctly by TF Java's SavedModelBundle load method. I am using this approach to avoid costly disk operations since I am using the model in a streaming app.

Additional Information:

- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 20.04 x64
- TensorFlow installed from: pip for Python 3.9; Maven for Java
- TensorFlow version : 2.7.0 on Python; 0.4.0 on Java
- Java version : openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
  Python version : 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot parse a saved model as a `GraphDef`. The `GraphDef` is the older version of TF 1.x models that were "freezing" the graph, instead of loading its variables dynamically.

Though it is still possible to freeze your graph in TF2.x, please check [this blog](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Save-Load-Inference-From-TF2-Frozen-Graph/).

Comment: Freezing the graph and parsing the frozen proto works! Nice blog post btw! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you have any difficulties to load a saved_model in Java, here is a library that makes loading models very easy:  [JavaTF](https://github.com/preafixed/Java-TF)

Let me know if it helps :)